# Are fallback images in <picture> tag always loaded by browser?

Tags: html, optimization, pagespeed, webp

I'm implementing webp images with fallback images using this html:

```
<picture>
<source type="image/webp" srcset="image.webp">
<img src="image.png" width="500" height="500" loading="eager" alt="text">
</picture>
```

In the Network tab of Chrome's inspector, I can see that the fallback images are being loaded by the browser. The net result is an increased page size as both webp and the fallback png/jpg images are being loaded. When I run a page speed test on GTMetrix, the report also shows the fallback images are being loaded and the score is getting dinged, which my client hates.

Is there a way to implement fallback images that will only load if the browser doesn't support webp?

I've done a lot of searching and I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. Every guide on implementing webp says to use the same HTML I'm using and doesn't say anything about the fallback images being loaded and causing performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

So I was doing some weird stuff with javascript to load images on the page. Part of that was creating an Image object which I then outputted to the page as the fallback image within the picture element. Apparently when you create an Image object in js, it is automatically loaded into the DOM. I removed the Image object, replaced it with an HTML string, and problem solved.

In other words, the browser will not load the fallback image within a `<picture>`.